# fixed header to oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i'm trying to write a select query with a joined columns in one column with a very strict column name and without the Apostrophe.

THIS IS THE MAIN IDEA

```
SELECT COLUMN1|| COLUMN2 || COLUMN3 AS 'AN ALIAS WITH MORE THAN 30 CHARACTER' FROM DUAL
```

(AS) is not working and because I'm working on Oracle version 12 a ("") will fire an error (identifier is too long).

is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple: you can't. That's called *limitation*. Though, I'm not sure I understand what you said by mentioning the 12c database version as it supports identifiers longer than 30 characters, while lower versions (such as 11g) does not.

For example:

```
SQL> select * From v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select dummy as "an alias with more than 30 characters" from dual;
select dummy as "an alias with more than 30 characters" from dual
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

---

```
SQL> select * From v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER                                                                               CON_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production              0

SQL> select 'a234567890123456789012345678901234567890' "an alias with more than 30 characters" from dual;

an alias with more than 30 characters
----------------------------------------
a234567890123456789012345678901234567890

SQL>
```